# How do I use GStreamer gst-launch to re-mux an interlaced h264 stream from an RTSP source?

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, gst-launch, matroska

Is there any way to take an interlaced h264 stream and re-mux it into Matroska or QT container form in a way that players will correctly identify it as interlaced?  My basic pipeline is:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e  souphttpsrc location="http://hostname/stream1.sdp" ! application/sdp ! sdpdemux !  rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv`

This saves the file just fine, but in all the players I've tried, the interlaced form of the video was not detected.

Comment: what about adding to caps after soup `interlaced=true` .. or maybe adding `interlace` element?

Comment: I tried adding `interlace-mode` on the h264 caps between `h264parse` and `matroskamux` and it didn't do anything.  The `interlace` element only operates on raw video buffers, not encoded video.